# Automation in EA is taking more time after applying user lock to model

Tags: enterprise-architect

We are creating an element in EA through automation .Previously it was taking some seconds to create an element in EA. After applying the user lock to the model and then creating an element in EA then its taking minutes to create an element. Then i observed that there is a table called t_seclocks which is getting updated when lock is applied. Even i observed that t_snapshot table is getting updated. So what is this t_snapshot table.What is the purpose of this table .If not required how can we disable this table such that this table is not getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

`t_snapshot` takes the audit log. So I guess you have turned on auditing. You might want to clear the audit log from time to time and re-organize your database. Ask your DBA.

Comment: No, you can not.